# Add "Change (answer) to comment" in review page

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, review-page

Some of the answers I reviewed are no answers, they are comments, but normally the user has not the reputation to comment.

To make things easier for the moderators isn't it possible to add a button `change (answer) to comment` in  review page for example near the button `Recommended Deletion`?

Comment: +1; Much needed; It would be very useful across all sites on the network. Perhaps, you could also post it on `meta.SO` or wait for the powers that be to take a suo motu cognisance of the request in question.

Comment: I also agree that this would be a great opportunity. If you decide to carry this request over meta.SO, I would suggest you to keep in mind that meta.SO is a *shoot first, ask later* site. So please don't get disappointed about the user behavior there :)